# Being confused with how the author describe the time frame

Tags: phrases

[Dasgupta,2019,p.2597](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/32/7/2587/5079300) said that

> the ***treated group*** comprises all firms that are headquartered in
> countries that have passed a leniency law by year t. The ***control
> group*** comprises firms in countries that **never adopted** a
> leniency law in our sample period and firms headquartered in countries
> that **adopted a leniency law at some later point of time**.

Whether the control group includes firms in countries that implemented this law at some **earlier point in time**? My understanding is: for example, from [Table 2, Dasgupta,2019, page 2599](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/32/7/2587/5079300), Korea passed the laws in 1997, therefore, the control group including all firms in all countries not implemented this law from 1995 to 2002, including the US.
From my point of view, it should be the case because base on this identification, firms in the US will not be affected by the laws passed in Korea based on this identification so these US firms from 1995-1996 and 1998-2002 can be control observations for Korea.

But if it is the case, **why they need to write down "adopted a leniency law at some later point of time"**. Because in Korea case, the word "our sample period" means "1995-2002" already.

Comment: Note "by year t."

Comment: @YosefBaskin I thought "by year t " in the first sentence is for "treated group". Sorry if I misunderstand you.

Comment: @Xanne I think you are mentioning the first sentence, and it is the description for "treated group". Thank you.

Comment: You're asking "Whether the control group includes firms in countries that implemented this law" before time t. The text says No: the treated group "passed a leniency law by year t."

Comment: And... the control group ***never*** adopted a law in their sample period. Us if the word *never* is unlikely if they are including those that at some point *did*.

Comment: The sample period is those that adopted a leniency law before time t.  "The control group comprises firms in countries that never adopted a leniency law in their sample period and firms headquartered in countries that adopted a leniency law at some later point of time."  Why is this ambiguous?  The control group includes firms that adopted such a law after time t.  There are only two groups, the sample group and the control group, and all the firms seem to fit in one or the other of the countries in which these firms reside.

Comment: @Xanne , can I ask "their sample period" stands for "treatment group's sample period" in this case ?